# How to add page number to title page?

Tags: titles, page-numbering

Because of some stupid format check requirement I need to add page number at the bottom of title page.

Here's a minimal working example that doesn't produce the page number on title page:

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\author{test}
\title{mytitle}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

What should I do to add page number to this title page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can patch `\titlepage` to change the default `empty` page style used there to `plain`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\patchcmd{\titlepage}
  {\thispagestyle{empty}}
  {\thispagestyle{plain}}
  {}
  {}

\begin{document}
\author{test}
\title{mytitle}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Without the patching, you can redefine the environment as defined in `report.cls`:

```
\documentclass{report}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{titlepage}
    {%
      \if@twocolumn
        \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
      \else
        \@restonecolfalse\newpage
      \fi
      \thispagestyle{plain}% the change was made here
      \setcounter{page}\@ne
    }%
    {\if@restonecol\twocolumn \else \newpage \fi
     \if@twoside\else
        \setcounter{page}\@ne
     \fi
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\author{test}
\title{mytitle}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @Gonzalo. I prefer `\pretocmd{\titlepage}{\thispagestyle{empty}}{}{}` and `\apptocmd{\titlepage}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{}{}` which make the intension more clearly.