# Add consecutive page numbering to title page in classic thesis template

Tags: titles, page-numbering, classicthesis

I am using the classic thesis template and in my document, I have added titles pages with a graphic at the start of each chapter. I would like to add a page number to the title page so there is consecutive numbering throughout the whole document.

I have tried the suggestions from [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210577/classic-thesis-consecutive-numbering-of-all-pages-from-the-title-page-to-the-ve) and [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170379/how-to-add-page-number-to-title-page) but without success. Note that in my MWE, I have two types of page numbering (roman and Arabic) and these are needed for the table of contents and main document, respectively.

I've included a MWE which shows the page numbering starting from chapter 1 and not from the 'Chapter title' page as required.

Any advice would be much appreciated!

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,headinclude=true,footinclude]{report}% or book for the standard book class
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[dottedtoc]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx, epstopdf}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, citestyle=ieee, bibstyle=ieee]{biblatex}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}%Allows you to permanently fix figures. 
\usepackage{titleps}%fancy page borders? 
\usepackage[left=4.0cm, right=4cm, top=3.5cm, bottom=3.5cm]{geometry}
\captionsetup{format=plain, font={small,it}, labelfont=bf}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\sloppy%Makes sure that none of the text exceeds text width. Useful if have long chemical words. 

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{-}

\doublespacing 
\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of figures}
\listoffigures
\newpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}

%CHAPTER_1
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{titlepage} % Suppresses displaying the page number on the title page and the subsequent page counts as page 1
    \newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}} % Defines a new command for horizontal lines, change thickness here
    
    
    \center % Centre everything on the page
    
    
    %------------------------------------------------
    %   Headings
    %------------------------------------------------
    
    \vspace*{4cm}
    
    \textsc{\huge Chapter title}\\[1.5cm] % Main heading such as the name of your university/college
    
    
    \vfill\vfill
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{Example_figure}\\[2cm] % Include a graphic/logo - this will require the graphicx package
    
    
    \vfill\vfill\vfill % Position the date 3/4 down the remaining page
    
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    \vfill % Push the date up 1/4 of the remaining page
    
\end{titlepage}

\chapter{Introduction}

\section{General}

\section{Aims}

\section{Scope}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of observations:

If you download the full CTAN class thesis package from this [zip file](https://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/classicthesis.zip)
you will find a complete example on how to set up a nice thesis. In particular, it is recommended to put all the configuration in the `classicthesis-config.tex` file and load it after `\documentclass {...}` to keep everything tidy.

If you want to add a figure before **each** chapter, do not use  `titlepage`, an environment to design the title page of your thesis, the first page of your thesis. Just add the text and the images you want. (I chose to have a blank page for the next page (even) after the figure.)

All chapters in a book-type class must start on an odd page, so if the first figure is on page 1, the chapter will be on page 3, and so on.

Note that the pages listed in the TOC will link to the chapter page, not the figure.

Use `\setcounter{page}{<number>}` to set the page number of the next page.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,headinclude=true,footinclude]{book}% or book for the standard book class

%%%%********************************************************************
%%%% Note: Make all your adjustments in here
%%%%*******************************************************
%%%\input{classicthesis-config}

\usepackage[dottedtoc]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}    

    \frontmatter % roman numbering
    \tableofcontents
    
    \listoffigures  
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of figures}
    
    \mainmatter % arabic numbering
    %%**************************************** changed <<<<<
    \cleardoublepage
    \thispagestyle{plain} % or \thispagestyle{empty}
    %\setcounter{page}{5} % use it to set the page number of the figure
    %CHAPTER_1
        \begin{center}      
        \vspace*{4cm}       
        \textsc{\huge Chapter title 1} % 
        \vfill
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image-a} % Include a graphic/logo     
        \vfill %        
    \end{center}
    \clearpage\null\thispagestyle{empty} %blank page

    \chapter{Introduction}  
    \section{General}   
    \section{Aims}  
    \section{Scope}
    
    %CHAPTER_2
    \cleardoublepage
    \thispagestyle{plain} % or \pagestyle{empty}
    \begin{center}      
        \vspace*{4cm}       
        \textsc{\huge Chapter title 2}% 
        \vfill
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image-b} % Include a graphic/logo     
        \vfill %        
    \end{center}
    \clearpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}%blank page
    
    \chapter{Method}
    %%****************************  
        
\end{document}
```